# PETSc memory corruption on using DMDAVecGetArray

Tags: c, memory-corruption, petsc

I'm trying to use PETSc's DMDA Vectors with 2 degrees of freedom and access them using struct, [like in the manual](https://docs.petsc.org/en/latest/manual/vec/#accessing-the-vector-entries-for-dmda-vectors).
However, when I try to use `DMDAVecGetArray` even with one degree of freedom (like in example below) I get memory `double free or corruption` error. When I replace `DMDAVecGetArray` with `VecGetArray` everything works just fine.

What causes this error?

---

Compile MWE with

```sh
> gcc -Wall -Wextra -O0 -g $(pkg-config --cflags petsc mpi) -o mwe mwe.c $(pkg-config --libs petsc mpi)
```

and run with

```sh
> mpiexec --host localhost:$(nproc) -n $(nproc) mwe
```

MWE:

```c
#include <petscdm.h>
#include <petscdmda.h>
#include <petscvec.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PetscErrorCode ierr;
#define E(x)                                                                                                           \
    do {                                                                                                           \
        ierr = x;                                                                                              \
        CHKERRQ(ierr);                                                                                         \
    } while (0)

    PetscInt    N    = 10;
    Vec     fg, f;

    ierr = PetscInitialize(&argc, &argv, NULL, NULL);
    if (ierr) {
        return ierr;
    }

    DM domain;
    E(DMDACreate1d(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, DM_BOUNDARY_GHOSTED, N, 1, 1, NULL, &domain));
    E(DMSetUp(domain));

    E(DMCreateGlobalVector(domain, &fg));
    E(DMCreateLocalVector(domain, &f));
    E(VecZeroEntries(fg));

    E(VecAssemblyBegin(fg));
    E(VecAssemblyBegin(f));
    E(VecAssemblyEnd(fg));
    E(VecAssemblyEnd(f));

    PetscInt size;
    E(VecGetSize(f, &size));

    E(DMGlobalToLocal(domain, fg, INSERT_VALUES, f));

    PetscScalar *farr;
    E(VecGetArray(f, &farr)); // replace this
    // E(DMDAVecGetArrayWrite(domain, f, &farr)); // with this

    for (PetscInt i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        farr[i] += 1;
    }

    E(VecRestoreArray(f, &farr)); // replace this
    // E(DMDAVecRestoreArrayWrite(domain, f, &farr)); // with this
    E(DMLocalToGlobal(domain, f, INSERT_VALUES, fg));

    E(VecDestroy(&f));
    E(VecDestroy(&fg));
    E(DMDestroy(&domain));

    E(PetscFinalize());
    return ierr;
}
```

Debian bullseye; petsc-dev 3.14.4+dfsg1-1; libopenmpi-dev 4.1.0-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. The key difference here is that when using `VecGetArray` underlying array is indexed using local indexes, and when using `DMDAVecGetArray` global indexes are used.

So, in order to fix the code I have to get not only the size of the array, but also the first index of the local vector portion.

Using function

```c
PetscInt start, size;
E(DMDAGetCorners(domain, &start, NULL, NULL, &size, NULL, NULL));
```

and then looping from `start` to `start + size` fixes the memory corruption error.